# Can I install Ubuntu on an APFS partition?

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, macosx

I'm looking to install 18.04 LTS on an APFS partition of a MacBook Pro; is this possible or worth my time?

The reason is that I don't have admin rights for my work-assigned MacBook Pro, and I would like to dual-boot Linux alongside OS X, for cases when I do need admin access to upgrade programs (such as R) etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At the moment, there seems to be only a FUSE implementation for Linux. So, unlikely.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! The preferable technique would be to create another partition for Ubuntu (if you want to dual-boot) or replace the original one (if you want to have Ubuntu only). Have you tried any of these methods? What was the result? Please [edit] your question to specify.

Comment: I've tried the former method on a mid-2008 MacBook Pro, with a FAT partition and it worked great. I have a work laptop that I want to try in install Ubuntu on, but cannot re-partition due to admin restrictions etc. I might just live with OS X for a while.....

Comment: OK. Keep in mind that OS X is a Unix-like OS, so you can use most command-line tools and techniques just like you would do on Ubuntu and install free software using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) similarly to APT.

Comment: @Melebius, yes, but Homebrew also requires admin rights.